# Assigning variable inside of closure javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, p5.js

I have closure function in which I am trying to pass the actual variable and then after doing something inside the closure function I want the result of the closure function to be assigned to the variable which I passed in the function.

I might be sounding stupid just look at this example.

```
var foo,bar,foobar;

    loadAsset(foo,'../assets/sounds/gameOverSound1_.mp3');
    loadAsset(bar,'../assets/sounds/gameOverSound2_.mp3');
    loadAsset(foobar,'../assets/sounds/gameOverSound3_.mp3');



    function loadAsset(varsName,cAsset){

        loadSound(cAsset,loadedAsset);

        function loadedAsset(loadingAssetFile){
                loadingCount++;
                varsName = loadingAssetFile;
            }

    }
```

So basically I need to achieve foo = "whatever the result is in loadingAssetFile" ,bar = "whatever the result is in loadingAssetFile" etc etc.

How can I achieve this?

**NOTE:** I am using a library called p5.js to load a sound and `loadSound` is part of the library which loads the sound passed and returns a loaded sound value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `foo`, the value is copied and then passed into the function. Inside the function any change will not affect the outer `foo` variable. You need to pass a reference type, like object to achieve the result you want.

You can pass the object which contains the properties and the property name which you want to change.

```
var obj = {
   foo: '',
   bar: '',
   foobar;
}

loadAsset(obj, 'foo', '../assets/sounds/gameOverSound1_.mp3');
loadAsset(obj, 'bar', '../assets/sounds/gameOverSound2_.mp3');
loadAsset(obj, 'foobar', '../assets/sounds/gameOverSound3_.mp3');

function loadAsset(object, varsName, cAsset){

    loadSound(cAsset, loadedAsset);

    function loadedAsset(loadingAssetFile){
         loadingCount++;
         object[varsName] = loadingAssetFile;
    }

}
```

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: Leart something new today,thank you very  much for your answer! I help me understand how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** [Suren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838133/873165) of using an object is probably better than using an array, I just wanted to show an alternative approach and explain in more detail about reassigning parameters.

Reassigning parameters does not change the value of the passed-in value.

```
var one = 'hello';

function change(two){
   two = 'world';
}

change(one);
console.log(one); // prints 'hello'!
```

Instead, you could use an array for this. Something like:

```
var assets = [];

loadAsset(0, '../assets/sounds/gameOverSound1_.mp3');
loadAsset(1, '../assets/sounds/gameOverSound2_.mp3');
loadAsset(2,'../assets/sounds/gameOverSound3_.mp3');

function loadAsset(index, cAsset){

    loadSound(cAsset,loadedAsset);

    function loadedAsset(loadingAssetFile){
      assets[index] = loadingAssetFile;
    }
}
```

And since JavaScript allows you to use strings as indexes (sorta...), you could do something like this:

```
var assets = [];

loadAsset('foo', '../assets/sounds/gameOverSound1_.mp3');
loadAsset('bar', '../assets/sounds/gameOverSound2_.mp3');
loadAsset('foobar','../assets/sounds/gameOverSound3_.mp3');

function loadAsset(index, cAsset){

    loadSound(cAsset,loadedAsset);

    function loadedAsset(loadingAssetFile){
      assets[index] = loadingAssetFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer.